# How can Insert data from array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to insert array data in to table. My table structure and form structure are given below. Please check and help me to insert data. Getting an error in browser

**table**

```
id  form_field_id(foreign key)   value    create_at    updated_at
1        14                      test1   2016-02-23    2016-02-23
2        15                      test2   2016-02-23    2016-02-23
3        16                      test3   2016-02-23    2016-02-23
```

**Form**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="field[]" id="field1">
<input type="hidden" id="one" value="{{ $formField->id }}" name="fieldID[]">

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="field[]" id="field2">
<input type="hidden" id="two" value="{{ $formField->id }}" name="fieldID[]">

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="field[]" id="field3">
<input type="hidden" id="three" value="{{ $formField->id }}" name="fieldID[]">
```

**Laravel code**

```
$formValue                = new Formvalue;
$formValue->form_field_id = $request->fieldID;
$formValue->value         = $request->field;
$formValue->save();
```

When I print `dd($request->fieldID);` and `dd($request->field);`

**Result of field ID**

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "14"
  1 => "15"
  2 => "16"
]
```

**Result of field**

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "asd"
  1 => "asdasdasda"
  2 => "on"
]
```

**Error**

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 678 and defined
```

**Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Formvalue extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $table = 'form_values';

    public function formValues()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Formfield');
    }

}
```

Comment: can you show your model?

Comment: @SarangaR, I have added model in my question

Comment: You can not insert php array in database table but you can insert json data instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have applied below code and working perfectly now.

```
foreach($request->fieldID as $values){
  $fieldsIdResult[]   = $values;
}
foreach($request->field as $keys){
  $fieldsValueResult[] = $keys;
}

$j = 0;
while($j < count($request->fieldID)) {
  $IdResult                 = $fieldsIdResult[$j];
  $ValResult                = $fieldsValueResult[$j];
  $formValue                = new Formvalue;
  $formValue->form_field_id = $IdResult;
  $formValue->value         = $ValResult;
  $formValue->save();
$j++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should insert your data inside loop
try this

```
foreach($request->all() as $value){
$formValue                = new Formvalue;
$formValue->form_field_id = $value->fieldID;
$formValue->value         = $value->field;
$formValue->save();
}
```

in your model add fillable values

```
protected $fillable = ['form_field_id','value'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried but getting only token value

Comment: @samsam Can you put the result of dd($request->all());